# how to generate pdf of languages other than English?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am using Itext to generate pdf files for the text I have. The text can be in different languages like Hindi, spanish, Telugu, etc...
When I try to save these languages(other than English) it is coming as blank, where as for English it is able to generate text in pdf file.

Do I have to set anything for the pdf document to generate PDF all the languages?

Here is the code snipper i have used,

```
val document = Document()

var localFileName = otherUser +  "_" + timeStamp + ".pdf"
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,  FileOutputStream(path
        + File.separator
        + localFileName))

document.open()

for (message in messages) {
    var source = if (message.isSource!!) "Source" else "Translated"
    document.add (Paragraph(message.time + "  " + message.language + "( " + source + " )" + ":" + message.message + "\n"))
   )
}
```

Can someone help me plz?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. you did not specify a `PdfFont` when creating the `Paragraph` object. As a result the default `PdfFont` will be chosen (Helvetica, regular, 12).
2. Helvetica does not contain the glyphs needed to render all possible scripts you listed. When iText asks the `PdfFont` "please give me the glyph for character x" and the `PdfFont` returns null, iText simply does not draw anything. That's why it comes out as blank.
3. Some advanced typographic features (ligatures among others) are only available using `pdfCalligraph` (a closed source addon for iText7). You need these features to accurately represent Hindi, Tamil (and various other non-western scripts)